# Can't exit WPF Application

Tags: wpf, exit

I know this question has already been answered but despite my efforts I can't close my app programatically. I've tried this, which doesn't work :

```
private void CloseAppCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
    }
```

and this (but Visual Studio 2010 doesn't recognize it) :

```
Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

Does someone know why these solutions don't work ? I thought it maybe was because of WPF vs WinFOrms, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The second is the way to exit a WPF applcation. What does VS say?

Comment: VS doesn't find Application.Current... I use System.Windows.Forms.Application. Is it correct ?

Comment: No, it's not. Your project is set all wrong, you need to set your references properly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Application.Current.Shutdown();` is the way you exit a WPF application. You've probably messed up your project references. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970678%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the references you need for a WPF application.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not at the beginning of the project, and can you tell me, because I don't want to make mistakes, which references I must add in this list just to access Application : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970678%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Build_a_WPF_Application_Using_MSBuild

Answer (score 2):

Found it !
I didn't use the right class :

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
```